oracle 19 insert multiple values
I am using oracle 19. I am trying to insert multiple rows. I looked at the oracle documentation and found this.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html
INSERT INTO people (person_id, given_name, family_name, title) 
  WITH names AS ( 
    SELECT 4, 'Ruth',     'Fox',      'Mrs'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Isabelle', 'Squirrel', 'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Justin',   'Frog',     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Lisa',     'Owl',      'Dr'     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;

I modified it to fit my needs. This worked.
CREATE TABLE people(
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(55),
  status int,
  phone varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO people (id, name, status, phone) 
  WITH names AS ( 
    SELECT 4, 'Ruth',     1,      'Mrs'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Isabelle', 1, 'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Justin',   1,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Lisa',     1,      'Dr'     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;

This did not work on dbfiddle or on my database. It complained ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined. Any idea why?
INSERT INTO people (id, name, status, phone) 
  WITH names AS (
    SELECT 1, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 9, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 'Ruth',     1,      'Mrs'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Isabelle', 2,      'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Justin',   3,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Lisa',     4,      'Dr'     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;

Next I looked at the second example here.
Insert multiple records in Oracle Database
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME)
    SELECT 1 'ok1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'ok2' FROM DUAL;

It did not work here. It complained ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. Any idea why?
INSERT INTO people ( id, name, status, phone)
SELECT 1 'John', 1, '214-444-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234' FROM DUAL;

I then found 2 more examples here.
Why am i not able to insert multiple values at a time by this code?
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2    INTO sales VALUES ('A', DATE '2021-01-01', '2')
  3    INTO sales VALUES ('A', DATE '2021-01-07', '2')
  4  SELECT * FROM DUAL;

2 rows created.

or
SQL> INSERT INTO sales
  2     SELECT 'A', DATE '2021-01-01', '2' FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 'A', DATE '2021-01-07', '2' FROM DUAL;

2 rows created.

Both of these methods worked.
INSERT ALL
    INTO people VALUES (1, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234')
    INTO people VALUES (2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234')
 SELECT * FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO people
  SELECT 3, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234' FROM DUAL;

Update.
These both work now with the suggested corrections by Paul W.
INSERT INTO people ( id, name, status, phone)
SELECT 1, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234' FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO people (id, name, status, phone) 
  WITH names AS (
    SELECT 1 id, 'jOHN' name, 1 status, '214-444-1234' phone     FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 9, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 11, 'Ruth',     1,      'Mrs'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 12, 'Isabelle', 2,      'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 13, 'Justin',   3,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 14, 'Lisa',     4,      'Dr'     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;

Updated dbfiddle.
https://dbfiddle.uk/lZb6GjDd

INSERT INTO people (id, name, status, phone) 
  WITH names AS (
    SELECT 1, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 9, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 'Ruth',     1,      'Mrs'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Isabelle', 2,      'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Justin',   3,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Lisa',     4,      'Dr'     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;  

In the above SQL, the 'select *' needs to expand to all the columns in its rowsource, which is the query block names. But the data in that block are all literal values without any column names. By default, Oracle will take the value of the literal expression from the top query in the UNION set and use that as a column name. But that means you have two columns with name '1'. The parent query block cannot distinguish between them and so complains.
Whereas this one:
INSERT INTO people (id, name, status, phone) 
  WITH names AS ( 
    SELECT 4, 'Ruth',     1,      'Mrs'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Isabelle', 1, 'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Justin',   1,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Lisa',     1,      'Dr'     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;

Works because that first row has a 4 and 1, so no duplicate column names. If you want to avoid this issue, explicitly name your columns. You need only do this to the first set in a UNION set:
INSERT INTO people (id, name, status, title) 
  WITH names AS ( 
    SELECT 1 id, 'Ruth' name,     1 status,      'Mrs' title    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Isabelle', 1, 'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Justin',   1,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Lisa',     1,      'Dr'     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;

This one:
INSERT INTO people
  SELECT 1, 'Mary', 1, '555-111-1234' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234' FROM DUAL;

Will work even without aliasing because because there is no outer query block attempting to reference column names (no wrapping select * from ()).
Lastly, this one:
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME)
    SELECT 1 'ok1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'ok2' FROM DUAL;

Needs to have the table name, not the keyword TABLE, and you are also missing a comma in that first row.

Thank you :). Everything works now.
https://dbfiddle.uk/lZb6GjDd
